# PHP: How to run convert imagemagick commands correctly?

Tags: php, imagemagick-convert

I have a simple php file that I use to run imageMagick convert commands from.

The issue that i have is that when I run my code, it doesn't create the image that it suppose to and I don't have any errors on my page either so I cannot figure out what the issue is!

I know I have the imageMagick installed properly because this works file:

```
<?php
shell_exec("convert input.jpg \
          -gravity Southwest   -background '#f48fb0'  -splice 0x44 \
          -pointsize 30 -fill white -annotate +10+4 'Some image Caption Goes here'   output.jpg");
?>
```

**But this doesn't create anything and no errors at all either:**

```
    <?php
shell_exec("width=`identify -format %w input.jpg`; \
  convert -background '#0008' -fill white -gravity center -size ${width}x30 \
          caption:"Faerie Dragons love hot apple pies\!" \
          dragon.gif +swap -gravity south -composite  anno_caption.jpg");
    ?>
```

I'm following the tutorials on here:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

As suggested I tried this code and it doesn't have any output and the image is not being created:

```
shell_exec("width=identify -format %w input.jpg \
convert -background '#0008' -fill white -gravity center -size ${width}x30 \
caption:'Faerie Dragons love hot apple pies\!' input.jpg +swap -gravity south -composite  anno_caption.jpg");
```

Comment: As the color coding suggests, the command string is not correct. You end the string with the quote before "Faerie Dragons". Use single quotes here as you do in the working example.

Answer (score 1):

```
shell_exec("width=`convert input.jpg -format '%w' info:` \
convert -background '#0008' -fill white -gravity center -size ${width}x30 \
caption:'Faerie Dragons love hot apple pies\!' dragon.gif +swap -gravity south -composite  anno_caption.jpg");
```

Try this! I'm assuming that you have input.jpg and dragon.gif files.

Comment: with this code I get the following error: Notice: Undefined variable: width

Comment: Which ImageMagick version you are running? Try this code in terminal if you can able to do it

Comment: ImageMagick 6.7.2-7 2016-06-16 Q16

Comment: width=`identify -format %w input.jpg`. try this. Check @Bonzo's answer. it's perfect. you should try to debug it.

Comment: I have tried that too. that doesn't work either! and I cannot use the terminal for this project. it has to run from the php.

Comment: Changing ${width} to {$width} in the @user7234862 example may work. This is a good example of getting all the code into one command.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would write the code although it "works" it is probably not creating the image you are looking for, but I do not know the result you require.

If you are using V7 you could miss out the identify part

** Code modified to change Shell_exec to exec on identify line **

```
<?php
// Read the width into a variable
$width= exec("identify -format %w input.jpg");

// Put the command into a variable
// Allows you to echo the command to show what you are actually running
$cmd = "-background \"#0008\" -fill white -gravity center -size {$width}x30".
" caption:\"Faerie Dragons love hot apple pies\!\" ".
" dragon_sm.gif +swap -gravity south -composite ";
echo $cmd;

// Run the command with some error reporting
// In production I would either disable the error display
// or remove the error reporting totally
$array=array();
echo "<pre>";
exec ("convert $cmd anno_caption.jpg 2>&1", $array); 
echo "<br>".print_r($array)."<br>"; 
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: what is this suppose to do? I get this on my php page when i run it: -background "#0008" -fill white -gravity center -size 990 x30 caption:"Faerie Dragons love hot apple pies\!" dragon_sm.gif +swap -gravity south -composite

Array
(
    [0] => sh: line 1: x30: command not found
)

1

Comment: and when i change your code to shell_exec ("convert $cmd anno_caption.jpg 2>&1", $array);  I get this in the PHP page: Array
(
)

1

Comment: And either way no image being created!

Comment: "what is this suppose to do?" I have commented my code so you should be able to see what it is supposed to do. Looking at this output "-size 990 x30" there should not be a space after the 990. Where is that coming from? That is why I have added the echo and the error reporting so you can analyse the outputs and find the error.

Comment: I don't know where that space comes from! I literally copied and pasted your code and that was printed in the PHP page. I haven't changed anything.

Comment: Try changing $width= shell_exec to $width= exec I never use shell_exec as I believe it is more for displaying some output. Either way I do not get a space. But shell_exec does not populate the $width variable. Your version of Imagemagick is very old. From what I understand the Linux developers pick a version of Imagemagick and keep patching it BUT they do not patch everything. I had a problem a while ago when my hosts did an upgrade and did the standard Centos install which was the 6.7 version patched up to date. My code failed but using a 6.9 version worked.

Comment: Okay, that made it work. However, it seems like its changing the font size instead of expanding the box!

Comment: Are input.jpg and dragon.gif supposed to be the same image?